# How to control ng-repeat in html table?

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to make a class schedule/routine with angularjs. But, I am having probeblem representing the value, mostly when I need to declare 'colspan'. I am using ng-repeat, but, facing problem in controlling it. 
Here is my code:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="day in days">
                <td>{{day.day}}</td>
                <td colspan={{colspan}} data-ng-repeat="time in routineTime" >
                    <div data-ng-repeat="routine in routines">
                        <div data-ng-if="routine.startTime==time.id && routine.day == day.id">
                            {{routine.courseId}}<br>
                            {{routine.roomNo}}
                            {{colspan= routine.duration;""}}

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </td>

 </tr>
```

The routineTime has following data

```
[
          {
            counter:'1',
            id:'08.00 AM'
          },
          {
            counter:'2',
            id:'08.50 AM'
          },
          {
            counter:'3',
            id:'09.40 AM'
          },
          {
            counter:'4',
            id:'10.30 AM'
          },
          {
            counter:'5',
            id:'11.20 AM'
          },
          {
            counter:'6',
            id:'12.10 PM'
          },
          {
            counter:'7',
            id:'01.00 PM'
          },
          {
            counter:'8',
            id:'01.50 PM'
          },

          {
            counter:'9',
            id:'02.40 PM'
          },
          {
            counter:'10',
            id:'03.30 PM'
          },
          {
            counter:'11',
            id:'04.20 PM'
          },
          {
            counter:'12',
            id:'05.10 PM'
          }
        ]
```

Suppose, when routine.startTime=9.40 and routine.endTime=11.20, then, I want to skip the time within 9.40 to 11.20. How can I do this?

Comment: What data is in `routines`?

Comment: you have to filter data within that range. and assign that filtered data to ng-repeat instead of giving it as whole.